# Spark : get specific value of the column map if the key exists

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, dataset

I have a column "price_map" in my dataset and it's a HashMap that is like this :

```
(usd_price,100),
(eur_price,200),
(jpy_price,500)...
```

Now I want to retrieve the price value of `usd_price` (i.e. 100), when the key `usd_price` exists in the map, and put it as a new row in my dataset.

I tried something like this:

```
    dataset = dataset.withColumn("usd_price", when(
            size(map_keys(dataset.col(price_map))),
            map_values(dataset.col(price_map))
                    .getField("usd_price"))
            .otherwise(lit("no data"))
    );
```

But it tells me that

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'map_values(`price_map`)['usd_price']' due to data type mismatch: argument 2 requires integral type, however, ''usd_price'' is of string type.;;
```

I want to know what is the correct way to do this ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why the posted answer didn't give you what you want. From the comment, what do you mean by "_but I also need to be sure that this map column `price_map` exists_"? Maybe you could clarify it.

Answer (score 1):

You can just get the map value directly using `getItem`, and use `coalesce` to replace `null` in case the key is not found.

```
dataset2 = dataset.withColumn(
    "usd_price",
    coalesce(
        dataset.col("price_map").getItem("usd_price"),
        lit("no data")
    )
);
```

Comment: thank you, but I also need to be sure that this map column "price_map" exists